# Robolectric dosen't calling Application.onCreate(), and I cannot get context

Tags: android, android-context, robolectric, android-application-class

Hello I have the following project structure

```
--App
   |--SDK1
   |--SDK2
```

In app I have some test for check SDK1 and SDK2.

In SDK I have a singleton pattern only to set the context by the application class that is in App.

And the context is set in the SDK1.singleton in the App.Application.onCreate

The problem is that when I try to execute the following code I always get null:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class CallTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {}

    @Test
    public void connectToSocketTest() {
        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("dev")) {

            Context context = SDK1.getInstance().getContext();

            assertNotNull(context);
        ...
```

Any idea why this happens, and how can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the recommended way to get app context in Android using robolectric. You can get your activity by using below code...

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
```

To get the app context, just call  `activity.getApplicationContext()`.

> **EDIT1**: If you're using the latest Robolectric version, use
> `Robolectric.buildActivity(DashboardActivity.class)` instead.
>
> **EDIT2**: Make sure your `SDK1` extends `MultiDexApplication". Add this` @Config(manifest=Config.NONE, application = App.class, sdk = 17)` to
> the top of your test class.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That isn't the problem, the problem is that the roboelectric doesn't run Application.onCreate, so I cannot get the context in my sdk

Comment: Why do you want to run test code in `Application.onCreate`?

Comment: Because, I want to initialize, the SDK1, in SDK1 have a singleton class, with a context, and i use that context, in a lot of place, and i can not pass by parameter.

Comment: Finally worked only with `@Config(application = App.class)`